# Adding shadow is UILabel Error

Tags: iphone, uilabel, shadow

I have UILabel showtext and I have written code like

```
showtext.layer.shadowOpticity = 1.0;
showtext.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
showtext.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
showtext.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.01,1.0);
```

And it's showing error "Accessing unknown "showOpticity" component of property".

Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shadowOpticity should be shadowOpacity

Comment: oh sorry i made mistake while typing here. It's showing error for all shadow option and yes i have written shadowOpacity in code.

Comment: try #import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>

Comment: Joris, if i want 2px offset which parameter should i pass to shadowOffset. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: That is off-topic in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `QuartzCore.framework` to the project and then `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the `.pch` file.